# Changing default Python from 2.7.10 to 3.5.2 in terminal so I can install pip

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, pip

I was hoping for some help in setting up a Python development environment on a Mac.

Background: I'm running a newly upgraded macOS Sierra 10.12.1, and setting up various parts of Python development on it. This macOS version already came with Python 2.7.10 installed - and I'd prefer to leave that alone for now.

So I installed Homebrew, and then used that in turn to install the latest python3, that is, Python 3.5.2; but I guess it's not the default for Terminal yet, since when I run the python -V command, I get this in the Terminal window:

```
Python 2.7.10
```

So now I've got at least 2 version of Python on my Mac, and that's fine I guess, but the latest Python one is not the one that is the 'default'. How do I set 3.5.2 as my default rather than 2.7.10?

(Backstory for why I want to do that... pip is not installed, i.e., when I go to Terminal and type in pip, it says:

```
-bash: pip: command not found
```

When I tried to follow the installation instructions for pip, I ran into a permissions issue, which makes sense I guess, since I don't have access to the Mac's 2.7.10 Python install, nor do I really want it at this stage. So I'd like to switch Terminal to take the new Python 3.5.2 as my default one, in which case I guess I won't have pip permissions issues...)

Thanks in advance for any help folks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The safest solution is to create a virtual environment running python 3 and use it as development environment. Check the following links:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html
http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Comment: So I am going to go that route, but need pip in order to install virtualenv; and to install pip I'd like to avoid missing with the core of Python permissions for the system's 2.7.10. Hope that makes sense, here's the error message when I run python get-pip.py

Comment: Virtual environment is installed by default in any Python distribution. Try typing virtualenv or python3 -m venv